# Is there a way to check if a value is in the column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns, the first contains codes, the second where I have to put values ​​according to these codes. What I'm looking to do is: assuming I'm on line 23, if the code exists among the codes between lines 1 and 22 I put 0 otherwise another value.

How can I do so ? I tried with isnumber(match()) but does not work well.

Answer (score 0):

In `B2` you could use `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:$B1,2,0),0)` and drag down.

PS  If you were to start from a different row number, you should reference with the following logic:
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A<row#>,$A$1:$B<row#-1>,2,0),0)`

Using it in the first row would throw an error, but it needs to search from at least the first existing value, so you'd have to start at row 2 as a minimum.